# Getting command Input with runtime java

Tags: java, process, runtime

Hello i try to get Input in java from this command: "ps aux | grep java"
I use this code but not work:

```
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps aux | grep java");
    InputStream stdin = process.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String line = null;
    System.out.println("<OUTPUT>");

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    System.out.println("</OUTPUT>");
    int exitVal = process.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

output in console:


Process exitValue: 1
Any ideas?

Comment: Try printing the subprocess's [stderr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream--) to see what's going wrong.

Comment: this is error:
error: garbage option

Usage:
 ps [options]

 Try 'ps --help <simple|list|output|threads|misc|all>'
  or 'ps --help <s|l|o|t|m|a>'
 for additional help text.

For more details see ps(1).
but why when i use this command in console i have good output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a single string to `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, it expects a single command and its arguments, which are automatically tokenized. In other words, your code is equivalent to executing this command:

```
ps 'aux' '|' 'grep' 'java'
```

See how `|`, `grep`, and `java` are all being passed as arguments to `ps`? That's the problem.

I suggest using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead, and running your command via `bash`:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command("bash", "-c", "ps aux | grep java").start()
```

This is equivalent to the following command:

```
bash -c 'ps aux | grep java'
```

Now the `bash` subprocess handles the piping between `ps` and `grep`, so it should all work correctly.

You could do the same thing with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, but `ProcessBuilder` is a newer, cleaner interface and thus should probably be preferred for new code. (`ProcessBuilder` is actually just *relatively* new, since it was added in JDK1.5, vs the `exec()` method being around since JDK1.0.)

Comment: Thx for help :)